# Can this Markov chain limit be found analytically?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm new to Markov Chains. I have this probability matrix:

$P = \begin{bmatrix}0&1/2&1/2\\1/3&0&2/3\\1/2&1/2&0\end{bmatrix}$

I see it's a 3 state(0,1 and 2) recurrent markov chain that looks like this:
[image]

I'm interested in finding this limit:

$ \lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n = 2 | X_0 = 1)$

I understand we start in state $X_0 = 1$ and we would like to find the probability of going to state 2 in the limit. So the probability matrix should be stable after running it many times. I know I can find a numerically value by taking the matrix power many times:
$P^{1000}$

But I would love to know if this can be solved analytically? I have tried doing some searching and I think it's possible to start with the $\pi$ vector:
$\pi = [1/3, 0, 2/3]$

Not sure... I would love your input on this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "probability matrix". If you mean the transition probability matrix of the Markov chain, then this one is incorrect. It needs to be a [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix). It also doesn't match your image, where you have $\frac13$ instead of $\frac12$.

Comment: You are right I made a typo. It should be 1/3 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by joriki
there is no MC with your matrix as transition matrix.
 (Perhaps you have copied the second row third column entry wrongly).

In an irreducible aperiodic MC with finite state space there is a unique probability vector $\pi$ with $\pi P=\pi$ and $\lim P(X_n=j|X_0=i)=\pi_j$. I will let you solve the equation $\pi P=\pi$ to find $\pi_2$.

Comment: @joriki Thank you for  the comment. I thought OP had found  the stationary distribution already but the one he has written is not correct.

Comment: thank you very much for the help - Do you mind pushing me in the right direction for the last part? I tried solving the equation but I I'm confused what the elements ($\pi$, $\pi_j$) are. I tried solving: 
$\pi = [x,y,z]$
P as defined in my question (the 3,3 transition probability matrix)

This setup makes sense to me, since when P does nothing to pi then we should be converged

Comment: okay now I understand I can find $\pi_2$ because $\pi$ is a vector: $\pi =(\pi_0, \pi_1, \pi_2)$.

Comment: Here is how I solved it. I found the eigenvectors of the transition matrix $p$. Then I looked for eigenvectors i the transpoed $p^T$ matrix with eigenvalue 1, since that means the solution is stationary. The I simply normalized the eigenvector that i now call $\pi$. It has values $\pi = (8/27, 1/3, 10/27)$. I was looking for $\pi_2$ so my solution is $\pi_2 = 10/27$ Thank you very much for the help!